# Dual screen no longer works with same configuration

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

Dual monitor display on work pc no longer works, after running fine for over a year. One monitor is plugged into the tower via VGA cable, whilst the other is plugged into the graphics card via a DVI cable.

I've been told you should only plug your monitor into the graphics card, yet I had no issues running this configuration for over a year (repeating myself...) and would like to know how I can circumnavigate this issue, or understand why the change.

I've attached a photo of the [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8rP5.jpg) on start up. Apologies for not copying and pasting error directly, but it's necessary for me to restart the pc in order to progress from the error message. I'm hoping for an extended display, not a duplicate screen.

Where I am currently is I've gone into BIOS-Video- Multi display; and enabled multi display (gets rid of error message at start up). Next in BIOS-Video- Primary display; if I choose Auto or the Intel HD Graphics option as the primary display, I cannot detect the monitor plugged into the graphics card. If I choose the ATI Radeon HD Graphics as the Primary display, then the second monitor (motherboard) can be detected but it wont allow me extend the screen, or use that monitor exclusively [(Photo for clarity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJvxd.jpg).

Any help would be much appreciated. I apologise if I'm posting in the wrong place...

Comment: First port of call is to perform some troubleshooting, using one screen - does all work OK plugged in to onboard VGA and then also all OK when plugged in to GFX card DVI? Also double check the BIOS to make sure onboard graphics haven't been disabled for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Works fine when plugged into the the DVI, but not the VGA. I've checked the BIOS and enabled dual monitors (however I never looked at the BIOS prior to having any issues).

Comment: Have you made sure the onboard graphics is enabled via the BIOS? Not sure what the dual screen option is you're talking about, what model is your motherboard?

Comment: Where exactly is that option sorry? What I've done is gone into BIOS-Video- Multi display; and enabled multi display (gets rid of error message at start up). Next in BIOS-Video- Primary dispaly; if I choose Auto or the motherboard to be the primary display I cannot detect the monitor plugged into the graphics card. If I choose the graphics card to be the Primary display then the second monitor (motherboard) can be detected but it wont allow me extend the screen, or use that monitor exclusively. I hope this is clear, I'll edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Is there an option to change the primary video device too the onboard GFX within the BIOS? Also, boot in to Windows and within device manager - can you see the onboard GFX and secondary card?

Comment: No, here doesn't seem to be. The options are Auto, Intel HD Graphics or ATI Radeon HD Graphics (I'll add a photo to the original post). Also, it's a Dell Optiplex 7010, coming back to your query in the previous comment. I do appreciate your feedback with this! - Am looking through device manager currently, will re-comment in place of this one with results.

Comment: Does it work if you change the primary display to Intel HD Graphics as per your photo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EJvxd.jpg

Comment: So, I've updated the drivers for both display adapters through the device manager, enabled multi-screen through BIOS as well as setting Auto as the Primary display (via BIOS), and now we're in business. Funnily the PC now thinks there are three monitors (one non-functioning) when I go to extend the display through the control panel. If you want to rehash this (or copy and paste) as an answer I'd be happy to give you best answer, as you pointed me towards the device manager. Again, thanks, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it's sorted, I updated with an answer with my two main suggestions that should help anyone else who stumbles across the same problem. That third monitor is probably VGA/HDMI on your secondary card, there's no cable connected so it won't work of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, there's several things to check here:

- Setting your primary display device to the on board Intel HD graphics within the BIOS.
- Making sure both your on-board graphics and your external card are seen within device manager, might be worth perform driver updates for both these devices, even if they both appear to be OK.